# How to set the separator inset to zero to get rid of the space?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, separator, uicollectionviewlistcell

I'm working on the collection view list cell and have a question about getting rid of the left side space of the separator layout guide.

[image]

I want to get rid of the small margin for the separator layout guide in the above image. Even though I'm using the collection view list cell, I saw there is a method for adjusting the size of the separator inset for the "tableView".
Like,

```
tableView.separatorInset = .zero
```

But there is no method for the collection view, so I'm guessing maybe I can do the similar stuff when I configure the collection view list layout, because using [showsSeparators](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration/3601202-showsseparators) property allows the cell to hide the separator. (I know I don't want to hide the separator, but I think I can configure the separator in here.)

```
func setupCollectionView() {

    var layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
```

//        layoutConfig.showsSeparators = false // -> I confirmed that I can hide the separator using this property.

```
    let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // setup constraints in here...
    ])
}
```

Also, my app is available on iOS14, so I cannot use some other properties like [separatorConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration/3727309-separatorconfiguration).

Does anyone know how to get rid of the left space for the separator guide, which is also available in iOS 14?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can remove the separator and add the view at the end of the cell with height 1 and remove the view from last index. IDK if it is the correct way but it will solve your problem.